# File upload got slow all of sudden on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, unique-permissions

I have a SharePoint 2016 environment (two tier), its running since last 4+ year. I have a  document library which has around 30K+ documents in it. Each document has a unique permission of read only to a dedicated SharePoint Group.

Since last few days the upload of documents got slow on it, even if I am uploading a document of size 10 kb even. Its taking 2 minutes around to upload. Rest of the site is working fine, all pages are load with normal speed, search is also working as expected.

I have check Database it working fine. Any suggestion from where should I start.

Comment: Do you have blob cache? Check maybe you have low space. Check DB size and transaction logs maybe you have over for transaction logs. Last one I checked network availability and latency.

Comment: can put some light in blob cache and from where I can look into it. I check the transaction logs it was 200+gb, my team has reduced it but no improvement in the performance.

Comment: when was the last time you updated the platform (CUs)?what is the average size of your site collections?

Answer (score 0):

After one long month to look into the cause of this issue. We didn't find anything and decided to switch to a different library.
As any template from built from the same library behaving is same manner (slowness). We decided to build a fresh library and make it exactly the same as existing library. Same columns with identical name and lookup column as well.

Built a PowerShell to copy document with metadata. We got problem in copying the lookup fields as it refers to item Id in the lookup master list. So built another PowerShell (let me know in comment if anyone want it) for this purpose as well.

after all, above, the new library is working perfectly fine with same (even more) file count and lookup columns.

> One suspect we have is that the hosting server got patch updated
> before this error started. We think that the daily upload job and
> server patch installation got clashed which led to some mismatched in
> the document uploaded and assigned item Id in it. because during the
> above movement to new library, we found the in-site content library is
> show 9 documents extra from what we were able to see in extracted
> document count in excel via PowerShell.

Answer (score -1):

It's depend upon many factors, i.e copying speed on your network, you farm infrastructure etc. As you mentioned you want to move it to SharePoint 2016, i think you have to test couple of methods.

RoboCopy: Map the SharePoint document library as map drive then use ropocopy function to move the files to DL.

Drag and Drop: In SharePoint 2016 you can use this functionality and simply drag the folders inside SharePoint library.

Open with explorer: this option also very help in a lot of scenario but you have to test the speed again.

Here is [the article](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/05/sharepoint-server-2016-dragdrop-performance/) which is telling the story why it is slow in SP 2016. I would also recommend to use the Edge or chrome browser for drag n drop.

Comment: Thanks Amy, but the issue I am facing is that only one document library has this slow upload via Upload button.. Rest of the document library in the same site are working perfectly fine.